# Problems aligning images and the column to centre

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having some issues having problems aligning three images to the centre at once, i have the float: left property but when removing that, the images stack on top of each other on the left side of the page. As you could probably tell from the code I was only worried about circle and column and not column2 and circle2 as I was using the first row to see if I could get the correct result and then apply it to the second row as well.

**UPDATE:**
**ISSUE WAS FIXED.**

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
         
    }

    figure {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 2%;
    }

    .rowfirst {
   flex: 1 1 25%;
   margin: 20px 10px;
    width: 20.00%;
    padding: 6px;
    image-orientation: from-image;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
   transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 2%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.rowsecond {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
   margin: 20px 10px;
    width: 20.00%;
    padding: 6px;
    image-orientation: from-image;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
   transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 2%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.rowfirst:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
     transform: scale(1.3);
}

.rowsecond:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
     transform: scale(1.3);
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.container {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    image-orientation: from-image;
    padding: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<h1>Portfolio</h1>


</head>

<div class="container">

  <div class="rowfirst">
    <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%" filter:="FlipH"></figure>
  </div>

  <div class="rowfirst">
   <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%"></figure>
  </div>

  <div class="rowfirst">
    <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%"></figure>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

  <div class="rowsecond">
    <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%"></figure>
  </div>

  <div class="rowsecond">
    <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%"></figure>
  </div>

    <div class="rowsecond">
      <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%"></figure>
    </div>

    <div class="rowsecond">
      <figure><img src="../photos/exp.jpg" alt="." style="width:100%"></figure>
    </div>
  
</div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adam.

You can use the code below, as your case is related to images inside a container block:

```
.circle {
margin: 2%;
image-orientation: from-image;
text-align:center;
}
```

In case you wish to align images as inline elements, you should use the properties below:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

As you commented that the solution above did not work, I suggest that you use it with flex-box approach - With flex-box, you will have images centralized in the middle of the rows (and page). The rows will also be responsive. Try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

.item {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {        
    padding: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

</style>
<head>

<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../photos/example.jpg" alt="image for testing">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../photos/example.jpg" alt="image for testing">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../photos/example.jpg" alt="image for testing">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../photos/example.jpg" alt="image for testing">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../photos/example.jpg" alt="image for testing">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../photos/example.jpg" alt="image for testing">
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Comment: @AdamFerreira but do you want to align the 3 images in the center of a row or in a column (one above each other)?

Comment: I want to align them in the centre of a row.

Comment: @AdamFerreira I have just updated my answer. Test that code, with flex-box usage. It's the most professional approach you may apply. Cheers.

Comment: @AdamFerreira have you tried the code I added to my answer?

Comment: I been busy today so i didn't get the chance to try it however ill try it now.

Comment: I updated the code in the original question up above, i don't know if i seem to be doing it correctly but nothing seems to work but i could also be doing it incorrect.

Comment: @AdamFerreira Adam, you are complicating a simple thing. If you want to centralize image rows, use my answer's last code block as base, and then adapt changing as you prefer. One more tip, the code you added to your question contains two identical classes (row first and row second), you should use only one of them in your HTML code and delete the other class. There is no need to repeat the same code twice.

Comment: I'm aiming to make it look like a gallery of photos that's the reason for two rows, when removing the second row it solves the problem but not something i'm really looking for but works.

Comment: @AdamFerreira if you place the code I made for you inside a Section tag, your photo gallery with 2 rows is done.

Comment: @AdamFerreira I hope I have helped you. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the right answer! Cheers.

Comment: I have managed to figure it out on my own but thank you anyways!